# IRC Bot Join Command Doesn't Work

Tags: c#, irc, tcplistener

I am having an issue creating a bot with C#.  If I have the bot join the channel before replying to the ping from the server, it won't connect to the proper channel.  When should I attempt to send the JOIN command to the server?

```
public void Connect()
{
    client = new TcpClient(server, 6667);
    stream = client.GetStream();
    reader = new StreamReader(stream);
    writer = new StreamWriter(stream);

    sendData("USER", System.Environment.MachineName + " 0 * :UnrealMegashark's Bot");
    sendData("NICK", nick);
    //It doesn't connect to the server here
    sendData("JOIN", channel);

    string[] ex;
    string data;

    while (true)
    {
        data = reader.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(data);
        char[] charSeparator = new char[] { ' ' };
        ex = data.Split(charSeparator, 5);

        if (ex[0] == "PING")
        {
            sendData("PONG", ex[1]);
        }

    }
}

public void sendData(string command, string parameter)
{
    writer.WriteLine(cmd + " " + param ?? "");
    writer.Flush();
    Console.WriteLine(cmd + " " + param ?? "");
}
```

Comment: how does your `sendData` look like? This might not even be valid commands for all we can tell from here.

Comment: Apologies, it's been added to the code now.